# Reveal div on link click with slide animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation, slide

Im trying to accomplish displaying different content when clicked on a different section, im using this code:

```
<style>
.content1 {display:none;}
.content2 {display:none;}
.content3 {display:none;}
</style>


<ul class="sidebar">
 <a href=".content1"><li>Link1</li></a>
 <a href=".content2"><li>Link2</li></a>
 <a href=".content3"><li>Link 3</li></a>
</ul>
<div class="content1 toggle"></div>
<div class="content2 toggle"></div>
<div class="content3 toggle"></div>
```

Combined with this jQuery:

```
$(".sidebar a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".toggle").hide();
var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
$(toShow).show();
});
```

Which works fine, but im trying to do a slide animation, so that once link for .content2 is clicked, .content1 slides up, and .content2 replaces it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `.slideUp` to hide element and `.sideDown` to show element, read more on the jQuery effect: https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

JavaScript:

```
$(".sidebar a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var toShow = $(this).attr('href');

  $(".toggle").slideUp();
  $(toShow).slideDown();
});
```

CSS

```
.toggle { width: 100%; height: 100px; }
.content1.toggle { background: #ff0000; }
.content2.toggle { background: #00ff00; }
.content3.toggle { background: #0000ff; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a827Lmuv/

### Bonus

Toggling the `active` class to control the animation by CSS

JavaScript

```
$(".sidebar a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var toShow = $(this).attr('href');

  $(".toggle").removeClass("active");
  $(toShow).addClass("active");
});
```

CSS

```
.toggle { width: 100%; height: 0; }
.content1.toggle { background: #ff0000; }
.content2.toggle { background: #00ff00; }
.content3.toggle { background: #0000ff; }

.toggle {
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
.toggle.active { height: 100px; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a827Lmuv/1/